# Javascript & Ajax - better way to populate objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm an old 'C' programmer and with Javascript always struggle populating my data following ajax calls; i.e. I always resort to using global references. I'd rather be able to pass in the objects I need to update. Here's one example of what I do now - 'app' is the global (I'd have used a pointer in C :))

```
treeMapp.login = function ( dialog_div, form_div, server_call ) {

// validate the fields
if ( 0 ) {

}
else {
    // send to server & parse JSON response (single line)
    var jqxhr = 
        $.getJSON( server_call, 
            $( "#" + form_div ).serialize() )
            .done( function( data, status ) {

                 if( status == 'success' ) {
                     // hack!?
                     app.user.username = data.username;
                     app.user.organisation = data.organisation;
                     app.user.loggedIn = true;
                     //close the dialog
                     $( '#' + dialog_div ).dialog('close');
                 }
                 else {
                     // login failed
                     alert( "login failed!" );
                 }
            })
            .fail( function() {
                alert( "login: server error" );
        }); // end var jqxhr =

} // end else (field validation ok)   

}; // end treeMapp.login()
```

What's the best way of updating passed in parameters?

thanks

mini

Comment: You're doing it the right way :)

Comment: Oh no he's not! (Well it is Christmas panto time :-P)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `app` as an argument to your `treeMapp.login` function, then within the scope of it it would be local.

`treeMapp.login = function ( dialog_div, form_div, server_call, app )`

Comment: tried that - get 'app.user is undefined ' in Firebug - it seems that app as a local goes out of scope during the ajax?

Comment: Did you include it in the call as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the data object returned by your jQuery result to app.user, thus avoiding the need for element by element assignment.

i.e. app.user = data

However, normally you ensure the global object can self initialise through a method, or you pass a reference to the global object to the method so it can initialise. Directly using assignment to global variables is (with a few exceptions) poor programming in Javascript as in any other language

**UPDATE:** the following shows an amalgamation of the answers...

```js
treeMapp.login = function ( dialog_div, form_div, server_call, theapp ) {
    var app = theapp; // may be needed for scope issue..

// validate the fields
if ( 0 ) {

}
else {
    // send to server & parse JSON response (single line)
    var jqxhr = 
        $.getJSON( server_call, 
            $( "#" + form_div ).serialize() )
            .done( function( data, status ) {

                 if( status == 'success' ) {
                     // not a hack
                     $.extend(this.app.user, data, { loggedIn: true })
                     //close the dialog
                     $( '#' + dialog_div ).dialog('close');
                 }
                 else {
                     // login failed
                     alert( "login failed!" );
                 }
            })
            .fail( function() {
                alert( "login: server error" );
        }); // end var jqxhr =

} // end else (field validation ok)   

}; // end treeMapp.login()
```

Comment: I thought about `$.extend(app.user, data, { loggedIn: true })` : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/.

Comment: Good idea, except that I don't like the use of global variables - see amended answer.

Comment: There is at least one global variable somewhere, `app` maybe? :D

Comment: I'm joking, I mean, the name of the variable indicates that it might be a leading object, maybe the topmost in the chain (application). The question lacks precision anyway.

Comment: @vogomatix - thanks, I agree, it's the 'passing the reference to the global object' that always defeats me - I always seem to get an 'undefined' error in the ajax callback

Comment: try using this (see amended answer)

Comment: @vogomatix - now get 'this.app is undefined' ? code runs if i remove 'this', but window.app.user is empty ...

Comment: just read this about .each(): 'The drawback is that the callback is called in the context of each value and you therefore lose the context of your own object if applicable. More on this below at Functions.' on http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Object

Comment: My apologies, I typed the above without using a Javascript debugger. I'm a bit busy at the moment, but if you get the opportunity send a jsFiddle link and I'll try and sort it later